# Finding drive sizes on multiple domains in powershell script

Tags: powershell

This is my first post, so hopefully it makes sense.

I'm trying to go through multiple domains and look at the data usage of every single drive on each server. I then take take info, add it to an array, and then write the array to a csv.

## ie

```
>DOMAIN-ONE 
>first drive: \\domain-one\e$
>second drive: \\domain-one\f$
>third drive: \\domain-one\k$
```

The issue is not with logging in, but instead it does not find all of the drives that exist and the drives it does find, it is not returning a size. This same script works on my local machine to give me all the drives, just not the domain. I think they are virtual drives that it isn't working with

## current script

```
$serverlist=@("domain-one","domain-two")


$username = "username"
$password = "pass123"
$secstr = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString
$password.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {$secstr.AppendChar($_)}
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $secstr


#set up array to 
$csvarray= @()

#go through each server
foreach ($servername in $serverlist)
{
    #check all drives a to z on server
    foreach ($drive in 97..122) {


        #set drive name
        $workingdir = ([char]$drive) + ":"

    

        #check to see if temp directory file path exists
        if (test-path $workingdir) {

            #get drive size
            $disk = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -computername $servername -Credential $cred -Filter "DeviceID='$workingdir'" |
            Select-Object DeviceID,Volumename,Size,FreeSpace

            $disksize = $disk.Size/1gb
            $diskfree = $disk.FreeSpace/1gb
            $disk.DeviceID
            $disk.Volumename
            $usedspace = ($disk.Size-$disk.FreeSpace)/1gb


            #create row of data
            $rowobject = New-Object psobject 

            $rowobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Server" -Value $servername 
            $rowobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Drive" -Value $disk.deviceid 
            $rowobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Drive Name" -Value $disk.volumename 
            $rowobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Used Space" -Value $usedspace 
            $rowobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Free Space" -Value $diskfree
            $rowobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Drive Size" -Value $disksize

            $csvarray += $rowobject


        }
    }
}
next

$csvarray| export-csv "F:\datausage3.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

IF i'm reading this right that's going to ask you for credentials for every single drive it checks, you should use `$creds = Get-Credential "$env:username"` and then simply refer back to $creds in the Get-WMIObject call like so:

from

`$disk = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -computername $servername -Credential $cred -Filter "DeviceID='$workingdir'" | Select-Object DeviceID,Volumename,Size,FreeSpace`

to this

`$disk = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -computername $servername -Credential $creds -Filter "DeviceID='$workingdir'" | Select-Object DeviceID,Volumename,Size,FreeSpace`

Also, you have "next" listed after the `foreach`, this isnt necessary to continue the loop it will do this automatically. :)

Comment: I should have included it, but I actually define $cred above.  The issue is not with logging in, but instead it does not find all of the drives that exist and the drives it does find, it is not returning a size.  This same script works on my local machine to give me all the drives, just not the domain.  I think they are virtual drives that it isn't working with